# How can I loop through collections of strings but not strings with commas in JSTL/JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, cas

Here is an excerpt from a jsp file I'm working with:

```
<%@ page session="false" %><%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

...

<c:forEach var="attr" items="${auth.principal.attributes}" >
    <c:forEach var="attrVal" items="${attr.value}"> 
        <attribute name="${fn:escapeXml(attr.key)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(attrVal)}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

...
```

Each of the attributes may be either a string or a collection of strings. This code works fine most of the time, but if one of the string values contains a comma then it gets split apart into two attributes.

What I'm expecting is output like the following:

```
...
<attribute name="FirstName" value="Adam"/>
<attribute name="LastName" value="Franco"/>
<attribute name="DisplayName" value="Franco, Adam S."/>
<attribute name="Status" value="Staff"/>
<attribute name="MemberOf" value="CN=All Staff,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=edu"/>
<attribute name="MemberOf" value="CN=Admins,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=edu"/>
...
```

What I get instead is:

```
...
<attribute name="FirstName" value="Adam"/>
<attribute name="LastName" value="Franco"/>
<attribute name="DisplayName" value="Franco"/>
<attribute name="DisplayName" value=" Adam S."/>
<attribute name="Status" value="Staff"/>
<attribute name="MemberOf" value="CN=All Staff,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=edu"/>
<attribute name="MemberOf" value="CN=Admins,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=edu"/>
...
```

I've verified that my "DisplayName" attribute is coming through to the from the back-end as a simple string just like FirstName and LastName, the only difference is that it happens to contain a comma. Here is a screen-shot of the the `principle.attributes` Map right before it gets returned to the JSP:
[image]

How can I differentiate between a string and a collection of strings in the JSP or prevent the `forEach` invocation from splitting strings appart on commas?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a test before iterating over each attribute, to check whether the type of attribute is string or not using [`Object.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) and then [`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29). If type is `String`, don't use another loop: -

```
<c:forEach var="attr" items="${auth.principal.attributes}" >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${attr.value.class.simpleName == 'String'}">
            <!-- attr.value is comma-separated string -->
            <!-- Don't iterate further. Just print it attr.value -->
            <attribute name="${fn:escapeXml(attr.key)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(attr.val)}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <!-- attr.value is a collection -->
            <!-- Iterate further over attr.value -->
            <c:forEach var="attrVal" items="${attr.value}"> 
                <attribute name="${fn:escapeXml(attr.key)}" value="${fn:escapeXml(attrVal)}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the value of `attr.class.simpleName` turns out to always be "UnmodifiableEntry". I've tried to do the test as <c:when test="${attr.value.class.simpleName == 'String'}">`, but then I always get a JasperException.

Comment: @AdamFranco. Can I see the stack trace? And what all types can you get for `attr.value`?

Comment: In the debugger, my 'attr' item in the forEach loop is listed as Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$unmodifiableEntry<K,V> (id=6807). 
Here is the stack trace when testing `attr.value.class.simpleName`: http://community.middlebury.edu/~afranco/notes/attr-value-class-simplename_stacktrace.txt

As far as I can tell this is happening because attr.value is a character array rather than a string...

Comment: Is your `attributes` type a `Map`? I mean `auth.principal.attributes`

Comment: @AdamFranco.. Ah! I think I made a mistake earlier. Rather than testing `attr.class.simpleName`, you need to test for `attr.value.class.simpleName`. That's because your `attributes` seems to be a `Map`. And iterating over it will get your `EntrySet<K, V>`, so, you need to test the `class` of `entry.value`.

Comment: Here is a screen shot of the attributes in the underlying `SimplePrinciple` class before they get returned to the JSP:  http://community.middlebury.edu/~afranco/notes/SimplePrinciple-attributes.png

Thanks so much for your assistance, no need to keep going if you're getting sick of this question ;-). I was able to use a work-around of testing `<c:when test="${attr.key == 'MemberOf'}">` which is a bit of a hack, but at least works.

Java/JSP isn't an environment I spend much time in, so I'm a little lost as to the difference between what looks to be a string or an array of characters.

Comment: @AdamFranco.. I am unable to understand, why is it throwing `NumberFormatException` for `"class`", as we are nowhere trying to parse a string. Anyways, I'll look into it. If I happen to find something, I'll post here.